# hiding assign button in ribbon dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have a requirement to hide 'Assign' button in the ribbon based on the user security role and ownership of the record. Is it possible? Only the owner of the record who belongs to a specific security role should be able to see the 'assign' button and perform the action.

Comment: Is there anything limiting you from just updating the existing security roles appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Just set or clear the Assign privilege in your security roles where needed.